# RxSwift retry full chain

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm pretty new in RxSwift and I have the following problem.

Given two functions:

```
struct Checkout { ... }

func getSessionIdOperation() -> Single<UUID>
func getCheckoutForSession(_ sessionId: UUID, asGuestUser: Bool) -> Single<Checkout>
```

I have a third function that combines the result of the two:

```
func getCheckout(asGuestUser: Bool) -> Single<Checkout> {
    return getSessionIdOperation()
        .map { ($0, asGuestUser) }
        .flatMap(getCheckoutForSession)
}
```

both `getSessionIdOperation`and `getCheckoutForSession` can fail, and in case of failure I would like to restart the whole chain just once. I tried `retry(2)` but just `getCheckoutForSession` was repeated. :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `retry(2)` on stream with `flatMap`

```
func getCheckout(asGuestUser: Bool) -> Single<Checkout> {
    return getSessionIdOperation()
        // .retry(2) will retry just first stream
        .map { ($0, asGuestUser) }
        .flatMap(getCheckoutForSession)
        .retry(2) // Here it will retry whole stream
}
```

In case `getSessionIdOperation` will fail `getCheckoutForSession` will never be called as it's based on output from first stream.